# Batch File to open Chrome and launch Python Dash App

Tags: python, batch-file, flask, plotly-dash, waitress

I have a Dash App I'm running locally on a few machines through waitress, and I want it to open by clicking a simple batch file. I would lke to improve two things: that it'll open chrome only after the Flask server is running already, and if possible that it won't display the cmd window at all.

Currently I have this:

```
@echo off
start chrome http://127.0.0.1:8050 
python route "script route"
exit
```

It works but it opens chrome first and I have to refresh a few times until the server is up. And if I put chrome under the python command It never opnes because the python command is never truly "finished" until you close the cmd window and the app stops (which is why I think it won't be possible to hide the cmd window completely)

I'll appreciate any help you guys can give me.

Comment: Test if the flask server is running and then only launch chrome. Depending on your OS version you might or might not have curl else revertnto `powershell` to not show the cmd prompt, search SO for `hideme.vbs`

Comment: Thanks! I am guessing I have to somehow try to run those two things parallel then (because the python script that launches the server doesn't stop or "end" as long as I need the server running, so the test has to run paralell but start a few moments later?) If you can give me a clue to how this is done, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have curl on your device:

```
@echo off
:Test
Curl http://127.0.0.1:8050
If "%errorlevel%" neq "0" goto :Test
start "" "chrome.exe" "http://127.0.0.1:8050"
python route "script route"
```

a slightly Shorter method using conditional operators.

```
@echo off
:Test
Curl http://127.0.0.1:8050 && (start "" "chrome.exe" "http://127.0.0.1:8050" & python route "script route") || goto :Test
```

Answer (score -2):

When you can use the some countdown time before running the server

```
@echo off
timeout 5
start chrome http://127.0.0.1:8050 
python route "script route"
exit
```

And about hiding the cmd this can be achieved by using cmdow https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/

```
cmdow /run /hid mybat arg1 "arg 2"
```

Comment: please read the help content of `start /?`. Also, never solicit  upvotes in answers or comments.

Comment: But wouldn't this only accomplish that it would wait a little to open chrome, before even attempting to launch the flask server? Thanks for the docs on hiding the command window!